# file_put_contents sometimes generates inconsistent content, why?

Tags: php

My site was moved recently and I started to get some unexplainable incidents. There is a very simple code:

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
file_put_contents('/path/some/where/log.txt', '<?php return '.var_export($ip, true).';');
```

sometimes its good, sometimes its bad. It saves the IP address what user had when last logged in. All in all, it doesnt happens 912839 times in a seconds.
Still, I had a fatal error and got this in this file:

```
<?php return '127.0.0.1';';
```

(the IP is fictional). See? There is a double `';` characters so this causes syntax errors. Im helpless, what settings is needed? I dont have opcache. Or the disk of the server is malfunctioning??

Comment: What error exactly? Quote the precise error message including stack trace.

Comment: And why are you writing to the file in this weird way?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected string content ";", expecting end of file

Comment: Typo: `file_put_contents(/path/some/where/log.txt'` should be `file_put_contents('/path/some/where/log.txt'` . But that would generate a different error than the one you've reported

Comment: First of, the file_put_contents call is bad, it is missing a quote on the file path parameter

Comment: It looks like a race condition (two PHP instances write to the same file at the same time).

Comment: Can't do the file_put_contents in a sandbox, but if we simply echo the value you're trying to write to the file, then it works fine: https://3v4l.org/kcLmO . To get more help you'll need to provide a [mre] of the issue you're having, such that running your code would actually generate this syntax error. Since you appear to be trying to write executable PHP code to a file, is the error actually happening when you later try to run that code? It isn't very clear - your problem description is pretty garbled. to be honest (see [ask] for some tips).

Comment: Have a look at the `LOCK_EX` flag of [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents) to make sure only one PHP instance writes to the file at the same time. Still, what you seem to be doing is weird all around.

Comment: P.S. _Why_ are you trying to write executable code to the file in the first place? Why not just simply do this: `file_put_contents('/path/some/where/log.txt', $ip);`? All that the code you've written to the file does is return that simple string anyway, so it's not like it's adding any real value to code which might re-use it later on. For whatever process is retrieving that data, it would be simpler to just retrieve the string from the file and assign it, than whatever eval-ing or include-ing you're (presumably) having to do in order to re-use it. It seems very over-complicated.

Comment: "it doesnt happens 912839 times in a seconds" - what's the point in writing the IP to the same file so often? Is there any other process reading it the same speed? Why not use a database for this?

Comment: What is the actual thing you're trying to accomplish with this code? Because there's almost certainly a better approach than what you seem to be trying to do. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I reproduced this error with multiple-writing, and LOCK_EX seems to solve this. However, I still dont know why it occured with a rare-event

Comment: Because maybe a multiple concurrent access collision doesn't actually occur that often? We don't know the context of all this, so we can't be sure. Again though this is almost certainly the wrong overall solution to whatever feature this code is supposed to be supporting. It doesn't seem to make much sense the way you've implemented this, as we've already said

Answer (score 1):

My guess is a race condition happening, two writes occur at the same time:

Consider two different length IPs, 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.100 for example:

```
<?php return '127.0.0.100';
<?php return '127.0.0.1';
```

Since the second line ends writing at the `;` and that the other line was longer, the remaining bits are left intact.

You should certainly try to lock the file before starting to write on it.

Also, this looks like a very weird functionality. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by writing an IP to this file? My guess is that there are a thousand better solutions to your problem.

Comment: I thought that too. But its a login feature by user, so it cant happening simultenaously

Comment: @JohnSmith is each user's IP record stored in a different file, though? According to your code sample, the path is hard-coded, so it would be the same for everyone.

Comment: I reproduced this error with multiple-writing, and LOCK_EX seems to solve this. However, I still dont know why it occured with a rare-event